# awstats configuration for custom IIS 6 log

Tags: iis, awstats

I have a stack of IIS logs with the extended logging options:

```
date
time
client ip address
user name
server ip address
server port
method
uri stem
uri query
protocol status
protocol substatus
Win32 Status
User agent.
```

How do I figure out what the `LogFormat` should be within awstats?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

From http://awstats.sourceforge.net/docs/awstats_config.html#LogFormat:

```
# Enter here your log format (Must agree with your web server. See setup 
# instructions in README.txt to know how to configure your web server to have 
# the required log format). 
# Possible values: 1,2,3,4 or "your_own_personalized_log_format" 
# 1 - Apache or Lotus Notes/Domino native combined log format (NCSA combined/XLF/ELF log format) 
# 2 - IIS or ISA format (IIS W3C log format). See FAQ-COM115 For ISA. 
# 3 - Webstar native log format. 
# 4 - Apache or Squid native common log format (NCSA common/CLF log format) 
# With LogFormat=4, some features (browsers, os, keywords...) can't work. 
# "your_own_personalized_log_format" = If your log is ftp, mail or other format, 
# you must use following keys to define the log format string (See FAQ for 
# ftp, mail or exotic web log format examples): 
# %host Client hostname or IP address (or Sender host for mail log) 
# %host_r Receiver hostname or IP address (for mail log) 
# %lognamequot Authenticated login/user with format: "alex" 
# %logname Authenticated login/user with format: alex 
# %time1 Date and time with format: [dd/mon/yyyy:hh:mm:ss +0000] or [dd/mon/yyyy:hh:mm:ss] 
# %time2 Date and time with format: yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss 
# %time3 Date and time with format: Mon dd hh:mm:ss or Mon dd hh:mm:ss yyyy 
# %time4 Date and time with unix timestamp format: dddddddddd 
# %methodurl Method and URL with format: "GET /index.html HTTP/x.x" 
# %methodurlnoprot Method and URL with format: "GET /index.html" 
# %method Method with format: GET 
# %url URL only with format: /index.html 
# %query Query string (used by URLWithQuery option) 
# %code Return code status (with format for web log: 999) 
# %bytesd Size of document in bytes 
# %refererquot Referer page with format: "http://from.com/from.htm" 
# %referer Referer page with format: http://from.com/from.htm 
# %uaquot User agent with format: "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible, ...)" 
# %ua User agent with format: Mozilla/4.0_(compatible...) 
# %gzipin mod_gzip compression input bytes: In:XXX 
# %gzipout mod_gzip compression output bytes & ratio: Out:YYY:ZZpct. 
# %gzipratio mod_gzip compression ratio: ZZpct. 
# %deflateratio mod_deflate compression ratio with format: (ZZ) 
# %email EMail sender (for mail log) 
# %email_r EMail receiver (for mail log) 
# %virtualname Web sever virtual hostname. Use this tag when same log 
# contains data of several virtual web servers. AWStats 
# will discard records not in SiteDomain nor HostAliases 
# %cluster If log file is provided from several computers (merged by 
# logresolvemerge.pl), this tag define field of cluster id. 
# %extraX Another field that you plan to use for building a 
# personalized report with ExtraSection feature (See later). 
# If your log format has some fields not included in this list, use 
# %other Means another field 
# %otherquot Means another not used double quoted field 
# 
# Examples for Apache combined logs (following two examples are equivalent): 
# LogFormat = 1 
# LogFormat = "%host %other %logname %time1 %methodurl %code %bytesd %refererquot %uaquot" 
# 
# Example for IIS: 
# LogFormat = 2 
# 
LogFormat=1
```